# I've been trying to run 'npm run build' on my react tailwind app and its been showing me the following errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, tailwind-css, web-development-server

here is the thrown in the terminal

```
> craco build

C:\Users\kaund\OneDrive\Documents\codinglife\project-dreams\react-projects\order-form\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\loaders.js:34
    rules.some((rule, index) => {
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined
    at getLoaderRecursively (C:\Users\kaund\OneDrive\Documents\codinglife\project-dreams\react-projects\order-form\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\loaders.js:34:11)
```

Comment: have you added the `craco.config.js` file?

Comment: the Docs :https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I updated the craco to the latest versions